# numpy perform operation on preceding array element without for loops

Tags: python, numpy

How can I perform a mathematical operation on a numpy array based on the preceding element, without using a for-loop?

For example, if I have array **a** and I want to perform the operation and save to a new array **x**

```
w = [628, 314, 209]
b = [12.391011, 35.691723, -46.3733415, -111.779]
a = b/np.square(w)[:,None]
x = np.zeros([len(w), len(a[0])], dtype=float)
print(a)
```

[image]

I can do a double for-loop to calculate the elements in **x**:

```
for ii in range(len(a)):
    for jj in range(len(a[0]))[1:]:
        x[ii,jj] = a[ii,jj-1] *.02
print(x)
```

[image]

But is there a way to do this without a double for-loop?

Using Python 3.8.3

Comment: This is basically `a * 0.02`? Except the first column is not set.

Comment: `x[:,1:]=a[:,:3]*0.2` would work, however, your question is not what your desired output is.